# How to pinpoint and use the last token per line in FOR /F Batch file

Tags: csv, batch-file, token, tokenize

I am using `FOR /F` to read the lines of a `.csv` file to perform `XCOPY` of various files from one location to another.  The columns in the `.csv` file contain the information of the source and destination folders and filenames.

```
COL1    COL2    COL3    COL4    COL5
1234    From1   Out1    Out2
4321    From2   Out3
1111    From3   Out4    Out5    Out6    
4444    From4   Out7    Out8
```

My problem is that multiple output folder names may exist per line (shown as Out1-Out8 above), and I only want to use the last one on each line.
My current batch file is as follows:

```
SET "count=1"
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1-5 delims=," %%G in (c:\test\INPUT_LIST.csv) do (
IF exist s:\destination\%%I\%%G.txt (
set /a "count+=1"
echo f | XCOPY c:\source\%%G\%%H\Source_Doc.txt s:\destination\%%I\%%G_!count!.txt /Y
) else (
echo f | XCOPY c:\source\%%G\%%H\Source_Doc.txt s:\destination\%%I\%%G.txt /Y )
)
```

This will check if there is already an existing file in the destination folder, and will then copy the source file from the source folder to the destination folder, renaming the file, and also appending an incremental number to the filename if a duplicate copy already exists in the destination folder.

Again, my problem is that I want to use the last token in each line to be used as the name of the destination folder, but I currently only use the value in column3 (`%%I`)

How do I make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read every line and parse it in another `for` to get the last element:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM get one line after the other:
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%a in (x.csv) do (

  REM get last element of this line (%%a):
  for %%b in (%%a) do set last=%%b

  REM using this last element of this line:
  echo doing useful things with !last! here...

REM continue with the FOR /F (process next line)
)
```

Comment: This does get the last element per line (which is then overwritten with the next line) but does not let me _use_ it.  How would I incorporate that into my above problem?

Comment: You ARE using it (showing it with `echo`). I inserted some REMarks to the code  to explain, what happens. I'm sure, you are able to adapt your `xcopy`command yourself.